# Ubuntu 16 - can't connect to wifi issue

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo

Hello everyone I'm new user of Ubuntu.

Today I've installed the Ubuntu 16 on my laptop, whole life I was using windows so I'm totally new to this system.

I was using cable connection but when I unplug the cable I recognize that system does not show any wifi connection...

I tried few solution from this site - neither worked for me and I think that I mess up something by pasting all those solution commands into my terminal...

When I was looking for nvidia drivers In additional driver menu I found something below nvidia driver - there is Unknow: Unknow (I think it might be the problem).
I'm lenovo y720 user - all drivers are made only for windows 10.
I just want to say something else - when I change the driver of Unknow: unknow in additional drivers for suggested on my cable connection stops working and the wifi doesn't work anyway.

Can anyone help me locate the problem?
I would be gratefull :)

@edit `lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A3` resault:

> 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device
>   [8086:24fd] (rev 78)  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
>     Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi   Kernel modules: iwlwifi 03:00.0
>   Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>   RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168]
>   (rev 15)  Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit
>   Ethernet Controller [17aa:3881]   Kernel driver in use: r8169     Kernel
>   modules: r8169

now `rfkill list all`:

> 0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN    Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: yes 1:
>   ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth  Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: yes 2:
>   phy0: Wireless LAN    Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no 3: hci0:
>   Bluetooth     Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no

and `uname -r`:

> 4.13.0-32-generic

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I also welcome everyone :)
Post edited. Thanks for those commands maybe they will throw a ligh on my case.

Comment: One more command result, please: `uname -r`

Comment: @chili555 It worked - thank you so much! :)